# Periodic work requests skipped with WorkManager in Andorid

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I implemented some repetitive task using `WorkManager` and it works just fine (runs my code each period with couple minutes sooner or later) in day time when I actively use my phone. On night time it skips a lot of periods and I wonder why this happen and how to solve this.

```
fun startService() {
    val constraintsBuilder = Constraints.Builder()
    constraintsBuilder.setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    val constraints = constraintsBuilder.build()

    val work = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        HttpWorker::class.java,
        40, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        15, TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ).setConstraints(constraints)
        .addTag("TAG_WORKER")
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        HttpWorker::class.java.simpleName,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        work
    )
}
```

> The result look like this:
>
> --->run 09:14
>
> --->run 09:54 (40min)
>
> --->run 10:33 (39min)
>
> --->run 11:53 (80min)
>
> --->run 12:33 (39min)

...

> --->run 00:35
>
> --->run 01:20 (45min)
>
> --->run 03:39 (139min) !!!
>
> --->run 07:14 (215min) !!!
>
> --->run 07:47 (30min)
>
> --->run 08:26 (39min)

...

Definitely this is related to the device activity, also note that I disabled power saving for my app (my device is Samsung Galaxy new model from 2018 Android 9.0). What should I do to ignore those many skipped periods on a night time(when device is not used at all).

**p.s. my app is not on Google Play so no problem with any hacks (but without root)**

Comment: I think it should be case of device manufacturer's issue that when device goes to doze mode, it disables all services except RIL/Network service. Try with different device manufacturer and check if problem persist or not.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: read this carefully and understand doze mode , standby mode

Comment: @Quicklearner - yes there is a Doze mode but I disabled power saving for my app. maybe there are some extra stuff I need to make to force my app do periodical jobs even on doze mode (my app is not on Google Play so no problem with hacks)

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation

[setRequiresDeviceIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints.Builder.html#setRequiresDeviceIdle(boolean))

> public Constraints.Builder setRequiresDeviceIdle (boolean
>   requiresDeviceIdle)
>       Sets whether device should be idle for the WorkRequest to run. 
>       **The default value is false.**
>
> **true : if device must be idle for the work to run**

thus if you add this constraint. your work will run at night !

```
constraintsBuilder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
```

Comment: I think it's a bit different as per their docs: **When set true, ensure that this job will not run if the device is in active use.** So if I use phone all day my job will be not started all this time.